# Wix UI: How to increase the width of built-in UIs such as WixUI_Minimal?

Tags: wix, wix-extension

Is it possible to increase the width of a built-in Wix UI such as WixUI_Minimal in one easy attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to increase the width of each and every dialog separately. Besides, don't forget to adjust the dimensions of the banners, but this can be done in one place:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.ImgPath)\NEW-BANNER.bmp"/>
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.ImgPath)\NEW-BACKGROUND.bmp"/>
```